# Pointer Works And Then Breaks Seemingly Without Reason

Tags: c++, pointers

Why is it that I can access the data held within the object after assigning the pointer WHILE I'm within the scope of the assigning function, but cannot once I try to access the same value through the same pointer but outside of that function?

The pointer is a member function and is assigned within the function. Within the function, that works fine. But, when from within that function, I call ANOTHER function which uses the class scope, the pointer misbehaves, presenting garbage data. Why?

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object{
public:
    Object(  ) { std::cout << "Object constructor called." << std::endl; }
    Object( const Object &in ) { i = in.i; std::cout << "Object copy constructor called." << std::endl; }
    ~Object(  ) { std::cout << "Object destructor called." << std::endl; }
    int i;
};

class ObjectManager{
public:
    Object * retObject(){
        Object *myObject = new Object;
        myObject->i=55;
        return myObject;
    }
};

class LogicManager{
public:
    LogicManager(){
        myObjectManager = new ObjectManager;
    }
    ~LogicManager(){
        delete myObjectManager;
    }
    Object * retObject(){
        return myObjectManager->retObject();
    }
private:
    ObjectManager *myObjectManager;
};

class Viewer{
public:
    ~Viewer(  ) { if( myObject ) { delete myObject; } }
    void ptrinObject( LogicManager * inLogic ){
        myObject = inLogic->retObject();

        std::cout << "Got path size of " << myObject->i << std::endl;       //correct
        std::cout << "Got path size of " << retObjectVal(  ) << std::endl;  //0?!?!?!?
    }
    int retObjectVal(  ) { myObject->i; }
private:
    Object *myObject;
};


int main(){
    LogicManager myManager;
    Viewer myViewer;
    //myViewer.cpyinObject( &myManager );
    myViewer.ptrinObject( &myManager );

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Object constructor called.
Got path size of 55
Got path size of 861280848
Object destructor called.
```

Comment: parenthetical note, you probably want to still assign ```i = in.i;``` in the copy constructor.

Comment: Am I not passing the pointer to that newly allocated object up into Viewer? And then when Viewer deletes isn't that value deleted?

Comment: Ah, there is a call to that, but it's rather odd to do it that way. You don't initialize that to `NULL`, and you delete it regardless of if it was ever assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Viewer` class, you are missing a `return` statement:

```
int retObjectVal( ) { return myObject->i; }
```

should work.

What you have is a method where some of its branches fall off without returning a value. This leads to undefined behavior. You are simply evaluating "myObject->i;" as a statement.

---

Another issue you should probably address is that your Object pointers are not owned by anyone and not being deleted anywhere. Namely, you are deleting your `ObjectManager` but nowhere does it `delete` the underlying object itself. You should probably figure out an ownership model there, have someone keep track of these pointers, and `delete` them when appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is:

```
int retObjectVal(  ) { myObject->i; }
```

There is no `return` statement in that function. You just have an expression with no side effect. As a result, we run into §6.6.3/2:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
>   behavior in a value-returning function.

It's undefined behavior what it returns, so it ends up returning some garbage. Just make it:

```
int retObjectVal() { return myObject->i; }
```

This is an easy mistake to make, which is why you should always try to compile with the highest warning settings possible. For instance, on gcc with no flags, I get no warnings. But with `-Wall`, I get:

> warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
>
> warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Good catch. There should be a warning for things like this. If not, turn on stronger warnings.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're not initializing `Viewer::myObject` so if you just do

```
void something() {
    Viewer v;
}
```

You may end up trying to delete an invalid pointer.

```
myViewer.cpyinObject( &myManager );
myViewer.ptrinObject( &myManager );
```

Both functions create a new `Object` but neither checks to see if there's already one allocated (memory leak). Then later, they immediately ignore that new object created and instead assign yet another new `Object` allocated by `ObjectManager` (more memory leaks).

Finally, `Viewer::retObjectVal` does not actually specifically `return` a value and therefore you are receiving "junk off the end of the function".

I suggest you look at your compiler warnings as any sensible compiler will have warned you about the first and third issues I've mentioned.